# Should I mention results that have not been peer-reviewed in my application?

Tags: graduate-admissions, statement-of-purpose

I am a master student trying to pursue PhD in mathematics. I have submitted an article to some journal, the result is about something is true. Now I want to mention the result in my personal statement by stating something like "I am able to prove that X is true". One thing I worry that the result has not been peer-reviewed yet. Should I mention it?

Comment: You may have different mileage depending on the result you're referring to - claiming to have proven P=NP without any peer review, for example, will have you come off as a crackpot, while an incremental finding in a relatively unstudied problem might be more reasonable.

Comment: Have you shared a draft of your article with an advisor or someone else who is writing your letters?  What do they think?  Would a letter writer be able to confirm they believe your result?

Comment: @AlexanderWoo Unfortunately no, but I guess I will approach them once more

Answer (score 2):

It is good to have a "Work in progress" section in the CV. That is the place for such things. I you are only at the beginning of a project, just give it a descriptive name like "Exploration of ..." and put it in such a section.

That might be enough unless you intend to follow up on it during study and then it can also be mentioned in the SoP as one of your goals.